# What is the negation of the AND operator when using if and else?

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

i'm using `if` with `&&` and the `else` comes after that.

Example :

```
$Name = "john";
$age = "30";
```

if I do this :

```
if($Name =="john" && $age=="30") 
{ some stuff }
else { do other stuff }
```

Is the else here means : `$Name !="john" && $age != "30"` ?? I'm a little confused about that.

Thank you

Comment: No, the else applies when `$Name !="john" || $age != "30"`.... "OR", not "AND"

Comment: You should also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: @MarkBaker that should be the answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Name == "john";
$age == "30";

if($Name =="john" && $age=="30") 
{
   // Here comes only when name is john and age is 30
}
else 
{ 
  // Here comes all the time when name is not john AND age is not 30
  // If age is 30 and name is not John then comes here
  // If age is not 30 and name is John then comes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

&& operator is only work when all condition are true

```
if($Name =="john" && $age=="30") {// both are true}
```

else condition is in one of them are false or both are false ,like below condition...

```
($Name !="john" && $age == "30")
($Name == "john" && $age != "30")
($Name != "john" && $age != "30)
```

Answer (score 1):

you may draw a truth table to better understand your expressions in more complex cases:

```
$Name=="john" ? | $age=="30" ? | ($Name =="john" && $age=="30") 
----------------+--------------+-------------------------------
        0  (no) |      0  (no) |                     0 (false)
        0  (no) |      1 (yes) |                     0 (false)
        1 (yes) |      0  (no) |                     0 (false)
        1 (yes) |      1 (yes) |                     1  (true)
```